# Не запускается Hello world!

Tags: java

```
package ru.helloworld;

public class helloworld {

}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("helloworld")
}
```

Выходит ошибка:

> Error:(7, 15) java: class, interface, or enum expected.

Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Что делать?" - устранить ошибку, это же очевидно. А что вы уже сделали?

Comment: Для кого в коде некоторые места подчеркнуты красным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```